# Impersonate a server

Tags: java, ssl, server, impersonation, handshake

Here is my probelm: I have an Android application that communicates with an API on a specific server, which has the IP address IP_Server, through HTTP messages and using SSL. I want to impersonate the API and receive the messages from the application (from one of my smartphone) on my computer and respond to them as I want (according to the API protocol). To do so, in my router, I redirect the route for the IP_Server to my local network and I assign the IP_Server IP address to my computer. Then, I run a Java Server that listens on the port 443 using SSLSocket. At this stage, I receive the connection request when the application wants to communicate. However, the handshake fails. I think that it’s a certificate problem but I’m not sure and I don’t know how to resolve this issue.

```
public static void startServer() throws Exception
{
   SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
   SSLServerSocket sslserversocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(443);

   while (running)
   {
       // Listen.
       SSLSocket clientSocket = (SSLSocket)sslserversocket.accept();

       System.out.println("Connection accepted from:" +
                           clientSocket.toString());

       clientSocket.startHandshake(); // This line causes a timeout.

       // Handle the request.
       threadPool.execute(new ServerThread(clientSocket));
   }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The easy way to do this is to design your client so you can inject any sort IP address.  This makes it easy to test since you can just run your test server as normal and the client will connect to it.  Both of those concepts -- injection ([Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)) and [Design For Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_for_testing) -- are software engineering principles you should learn about.

Comment: @markspace how does that relate with the SSL handshake problem? Have you read the text in the question?

Comment: I can run SSL on my laptop.  It's not a problem.  If the OP needs advice on how to configure SSL on a test system, he should ask.

Comment: @markspace that's basically his question...

Comment: Well that crap bit of Java code he showed isn't going to do anything for a server config.  Why is he showing us the client code if he needs help with a server?

Comment: The **whole point** of SSL is that you cannot do this. This is basically a MITM attack. Any half decent HTTPS client will detect this and baulk. So, unless the certificates are under your control, you cannot do this. Nor should you be able to - for obvious reasons.